# Publish a sub tree to a different GIT repository

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

I know there are sub trees and sub modules within GIT but i am still not sure which one would be the best option in my case.

So the situation is this:

- I have a project with "lib1" and "lib2", project and repo are already there, i am not starting from scratch
- I want to keep all the project in the same GIT repo for easier checkin/checkout and since i mainly work on that repo
- Project is not open source but i would like to open source "lib2"
- I will never work on "lib2" alone, only within the main project
- I am not expecting contributions to lib2 so merging from its repo its a minor issue
- Ideally i'd like this to be transparent to other devs working on this project (so when they commit/push they won't need to know that there is a subtree below)

So, the idea would be to be able to push "lib2" with its own history keeping all the rest of the project private. I know there are a lot of questions on this topic already but i wasnt able to find a clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leave the repository as it is and export this lib using:

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filer lib2
```

`git help filer-branch` says:

```
   --subdirectory-filter <directory>
       Only look at the history which touches the given subdirectory.
       The result will contain that directory (and only that) as its project root.
```

Developers of your project will not notice any change, because there is no change. - However updating that exported library would require you to run another filter-branch.

Comment: This will fiter the history but how can i then push "lib2" to its own repo? Should i use subtree then?

Comment: It will create a new branch containing only this directory. You can simply push that branch to another repository: `git push otherrep branch`

Comment: just as a sidenode this approach works however it's kind of difficult to automatically push things to the remote repo once you change something because after filter-branch + push you have to hard reset to head to avoid issues on your main repo